# In JNI, is there a more portable way than jlong to encapsulate a pointer?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I've seen examples of using a `long`/`jlong` to allow a Java object to hold onto a C++ pointer:

```
class Foo {
    private native long create();
}

struct Foo { };

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_Foo_create
  (JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
    return (jlong) (new Foo);
}
```

This makes me feel just a little bit nervous because it assumes that a pointer will fit in 64 bits; that is untrue for example on OS/400.

Is there a safer solution, for example a Java standard library class that encapsulates a C++ pointer?

Comment: The closest thing i can see to a pointer would be `jobject`.  But i'm not sure how much that'd break if you aren't pointing at Java objects with it.  Far as i can tell, Java would very much prefer that you return a Java object, not a pointer.  And that means calling the constructor for `Foo`, JNI-style.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a hashtable to store pointers and return key of this hashtable to a user. Like:

```
 std::unordered_map<long, Foo*> handles;
 long newHandle = 0
 ...
  JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_Foo_create
  (JNIEnv *, jobject)
   {
       Foo* ptr = new Foo;
       long handle = newHandle;
       handles.insert(std::pair<long, Foo*>(newHandle++, ptr));
       return handle;
   }
```

Now you can use a handle to get pointer from the hashmap:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Foo_use
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jlong handle) {
   auto iter = handles.find(handle);
   if (iter != handles.end()) {
       Foo* ptr = iter->second;
       // use Foo* here
   }
}
```

Also this method will help you to check if an object was already deleted or to delete all Foo object that still exist.
The drawbacks are that access to hashmap to get a pointer can decrease performance. Also you should probably guard with your handles map from multithread access or use thread-safe map implementation.

Alternatively, if you need to implement wrappers for Java, I would recommend to consider [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) (Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator).

Comment: I've used this method before, although what I did was to just make a C array and return an integer as an index into the array; either way should work.

Comment: Neither `newHandle++` nor `std::unordered_map` operations are multithread-safe.  Given that JVMs are inherently multithreaded, this code is a great way to get unexplained bugs that can't be duplicated.  Pretty much the entire body of `Java_Foo_create()` needs to be protected by a mutex or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Error checking skipped for brevity:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Foo_create(JNIEnv * env, jobject) {
  Foo* ptr = new Foo;
  return env->NewDirectByteBuffer(&ptr, sizeof(ptr));
}

/* private */ const Foo* from_jobject(JNIEnv * env, jobject java_foo) {
  return (reinterpret_cast<Foo**>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(java_foo)))[0];
}
```

See also http://rkennke.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/efficient-jni-programming-iv-wrapping-native-data-objects/.

Answer (score 0):

Although `jobject` is defined as a pointer, it smells because it is not a valid JVM object. (I don't know if it would cause any problems if you were careful not to treat it as a JVM object.)

You might try a `jobject` returned by `NewDirectByteBuffer`. It both captures a pointer and creates a valid JVM object.

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Foo_create
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject)
{
    Foo *pFoo = new Foo();
    return env->NewDirectByteBuffer(pFoo, sizeof(Foo)); 
}
```

Also, be sure to consider lifetime management and other issues raised in IvanMushketyk's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20813649/2226988). And, do take a look at JNA (via JNAerator) and SWIG as alternatives to writing your own JNI code. Their output might not be portable but their build processes could be.

Comment: one can create (on the native side) a `NewDirectByteBuffer(sizeof(Foo*))` and return the resulting ByteBuffer to Java!

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of the byte buffer wrapping the Foo object itself. See the code I added to my answer.

Comment: @AlexCohn It works with OpenJDK but Oracle docs unfortunately say capacity must positive. So, I'll remove the suggestion of using 0. Thanks.

Comment: This solution is good in that it exposes the whole **Foo** structure to Java (using ByteBuffer get/put methods). The method that I propose makes the native object protected from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but compile-time check can help:

```
static_assert(sizeof(void*) <= sizeof(jlong), "Unsupported architecture");
```